# THREE load a video to custom shader material

Tags: javascript, video, three.js

I'm loading a video onto a animated WebGL plane (with custom shader material). Using a pre-loaded video I use canvas to draw an image of the video, and I then pass that on to my shader uniforms in my render loop:

```
// Render loop
useFrame(() => {
   // Video = video HTML element
   video.currentTime = currentTime;
   context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

   plane.material.uniforms[
      "uTexture"
   ].value = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);

   currentTime += 1 / 30;
}
```

This works, but it's not really performant, as I have to:

- Draw an image in context every frame
- Create a new instance of THREE's Canvas every frame

What I actually want is to have a buffer with frames (or CanvasMaterial instances) beforehand that I can iterate on in my render loop. Although I do have the code, I'm assuming this is a bad idea as my 1 minute video has to play out first?

I was wondering if my solution of pre-rendering is possible in a few seconds, or if there is another better way of performant video rendering to a custom shader material?

Comment: Have you seen this example? https://threejs.org/examples/?q=video#webgl_materials_video

Comment: My bad, I looked into VideoTexture but I was somehow thinking it would take over my material, stupid. I was thinking into using it before, but then how do I read it out in my render loop? I'm doing image manipulation in my shaders, so I guess I have to pass every frame as uniform? @prisoner849

Comment: You can pass it as a usual texture in your shader.

Comment: Yep, I was overcomplicating things, should've used videoTexture in the first place, you can just call texture.update() in the render loop. Thanks a lot. @prisoner849

Comment: No need to update texture in render loop. _This is almost the same as the base Texture class, except that it continuosly sets needsUpdate to true so that the texture is updated as the video plays._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @prisoner849, I can just pass a pre-loaded video as a texture to my shader using `THREE.VideoTexture`, without having to do anything in my render loop, as shown in this example:

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=video#webgl_materials_video